# How to wait the loading spinner disappears in Cypress

Tags: cypress

When I run Cypress, the page of my application shows the loading spinner spinning indefinitely. While it is spinning the other components of the page are not displayed, so I need this spinner to disappear.

What I did

```
it('should wait spinner dissapears', function () {
        cy.waitUntil(function () {
            return cy.get('im-loader.hydrated')
.shadow()
.find('im-spinner.hydrated')
.should('not.be.visible');
      })
})
```

but Cypress times out retrying `im-spinner.hydrated` not to be visible

when I replace `.should(not.be.visible)` to `should('not.exist')`  Cypress also times out: Expected <im-spinner.hydrated> not to exist in the DOM, but it was continuously found.
This is the HTML code

[image]

Is there any way to wait for the spinner to disappear and load correctly the page?
This is the Test runner log
[image]

Comment: Why is the spinner there in the first place? Are you waiting for some network request? If so, perhaps you can wait for that instead of some DOM element.

Comment: i am new to cypress so just a question the spinner loads indefinitely only when using cypress ?

Comment: @PDHide yes, the spinner just loads indefinitely when using cypress

Comment: @pavelsaman sorry, what you mean by first place? I updated my question with the test runner result. I am trying to wait for the network request. So I did ```                                                                    cy.intercept('myURK/customer/*').as('getCompanies') ```  // I want wait the URL after customer
```cy.visit('myURL/customer/companies') ```
``` cy.wait('@getCompanies') ```  The test passed but the spinner is still spinning

Answer (score 2):

```
it('should wait spinner dissapears', function () {
      cy.get('im-loader.hydrated',{"timeout":12000})
.find('im-spinner.hydrated')
.should('not.be.visible');
     
})
```

could you try this instead ? cy.get() has a default timeout of 4 sec it also can be modified by passing the options

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Arguments

Or

```
cy.get(path).invoke('attr', 'value').then($initialVal => {
    //It's better if you can do your click operation here

    //Wait untill the element changes
    cy.get(path).then($newVal => {
        cy.waitUntil(() => $newVal[0].value !== $initialVal, {
            //optional timeouts and error messages
            errorMsg: "was expeting some other Value but got : " + $initialVal,
            timeout: 10000, 
            interval: 500 
          }).then(() => {
            cy.log("Foudn a difference in values")
        })
    })
})
```

see this discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897411/cypress-wait-until-wait-for-element-attribute-to-change

Comment: I did ``` cy.get('im-loader.hydrated',{"timeout":1200000}).shadow().find('im-spinner.hydrated').should('not.be.visible'); ``` but Cypress again timesout in 4secs. On my cypress.json I have ```{"pageLoadTimeout": 900000,
"includeShadowDom": true,
"modifyObstructiveCode":false,
"responseTimeout": 120000,
 "chromeWebSecurity":false,
 "numTestKeptInMemory":0,
 "waitForAnimations": true
}```

Comment: I removed the shadow as you suggested.Strangely, Cypress times out after 4000ms and not after 12000ms expecting im-spinner not to be visible. So I tried ```cy.get('im-loader.hydrated').find('im-spinner.hydrated',{"timeout":12000}).should('not.be.visible')```. Then Cypress times out retrying after 12000ms expecting '<im-spinner.hydrated>' not to be 'visible'